# Custom Lint does not highlight in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, lint

I have my custom lint, that checks XML files for hex colors usage.

It works perfectly when I run

```
./gradlew myapp:lint
```

But it does not hightlight problem places. Even more - **Analyze** -> **Inspect Code** does not give me result and returns only

> No suspicious code found.

Source Code:

```
class XmlColorsDetector : ResourceXmlDetector() {

    companion object {
        val ISSUE: Issue = Issue.create(
            id = "CustomColorsXml",
            briefDescription = "Custom colors detector",
            explanation = "Use only theme colors, in other case our themes behaviour will not work properly",
            category = Category.CORRECTNESS,
            priority = 6,
            severity = Severity.ERROR,
            implementation = Implementation(
                XmlColorsDetector::class.java,
                Scope.RESOURCE_FILE_SCOPE
            )
        )
    }

    override fun getApplicableAttributes(): Collection<String>? {
        return listOf("color", "textColor", "background")
    }

    override fun getApplicableElements(): Collection<String>? {
        return listOf("color")
    }

    override fun visitAttribute(context: XmlContext, attribute: Attr) {
        if (attribute.textContent.startsWith("#") && !context.file.path.containsExcludes()) {
            println("uri" + context.file.path)
            context.report(ISSUE, context.getLocation(attribute), "You can not use hardcoded colors")
        }
    }

    private fun String.containsExcludes(): Boolean {
        val excludes = listOf("/color", "/drawable")
        excludes.forEach {
            if (this.contains(it))
                return true
        }
        return false
    }
 }
```

I tried `LintFix` but it nothing changed.

How can I achieve a proper hightlight in Android Studio?

Comment: hey did you manage to do something about it?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Even in Google's sample project with AS 4.2.2.